# 3 tier application problem

Tags: sql, database, visual-studio, web-services

For school we have to make a 3tier application. With a data-base,webservice and client part.
Now i have the following stored procedure,

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.addMovie
(
@film_naam nvarchar(50),
@film_hoofdrol nvarchar(50)

)
AS
/* SET NOCOUNT ON */
INSERT INTO tbl_film 
     (film_naam, film_status, film_hoofdrol)
     VALUES(@film_naam,0,@film_hoofdrol)
RETURN
```

When i execute this, it works great. But when i tried it in my webservice I get the following error.

> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>      at Movie_rent.Movie_rentDB.addMovie(String film_naam, String film_hoofdrol) in D:\School\Programmeren VB.net\Periode 2\Movie_rent\Movie_rent\App_code\Movie_rentDB.vb:line 105
>      at Movie_rent.Movie_web.addMovie(String film_naam, String film_hoofdrol) in D:\School\Programmeren VB.net\Periode 2\Movie_rent\Movie_rent\Movie_web.asmx.vb:line 40

My webservice part

```
  <WebMethod()> _
Public Function addMovie(ByVal film_naam As String, ByVal film_hoofdrol As String) As Boolean
    Dim Movie_rent As New Movie_rentDB()
    Return Movie_rent.addMovie(film_naam, film_hoofdrol)
End Function
```

And my Movie_rentDB class

```
Public Class Movie_rentDB
Private strApplicationName As String = "Movie rent"

Private strConnection As String
Private conMovie As SqlConnection
Private adapMovie As New SqlDataAdapter
Private CommandMovie As SqlCommand
Private DataSetMovie As New DataSet

Private sqlTransaction As SqlTransaction
Private objLoggingService As Logging.Logging = New Logging.Logging("d:\\WebService.log")

Public ReadOnly Property ConnectionString() As String
    Get
        Try
            Return ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("Movie_rent").ConnectionString

        Catch ex As Exception
            objLoggingService.WriteLine(strApplicationName, ex.Message)
            Throw (ex)
        End Try
        Return ""
    End Get
End Property

Public Sub CreateConnection()
    Try
        conMovie = New SqlConnection(ConnectionString)
    Catch ex As Exception
        objLoggingService.WriteLine(strApplicationName, ex.Message)
        Throw (ex)
    End Try
End Sub
Private Sub Prepare_StoredProcedureCall(ByVal strStoredProcedure As String)
    Try
        CommandMovie = New SqlCommand(strStoredProcedure, conMovie)
        CommandMovie.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure

        adapMovie = New SqlDataAdapter(CommandMovie)
        DataSetMovie = New DataSet()

        conMovie.Open()

        sqlTransaction = conMovie.BeginTransaction
        CommandMovie.Transaction = sqlTransaction

    Catch ex As Exception
        objLoggingService.WriteLine(strApplicationName, ex.Message)
        Throw (ex)
    End Try
End Sub
Private Sub Finish_StoredProcedureCall()
    Try
        If (conMovie.State = ConnectionState.Open) Then
            conMovie.Close()
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        objLoggingService.WriteLine(strApplicationName, ex.Message)
        Throw (ex)
    End Try
End Sub
Public Function getAllMovies() As DataSet
    Try
        Prepare_StoredProcedureCall("getAllMovies")
        adapMovie.Fill(DataSetMovie, "tbl_film")
        sqlTransaction.Commit()
    Catch ex As Exception
        If Not (sqlTransaction Is Nothing) Then
            sqlTransaction.Rollback()
        End If
        DataSetMovie = Nothing
        objLoggingService.WriteLine(strApplicationName, ex.Message)
        Throw (ex)
    End Try
    Try
        Finish_StoredProcedureCall()
    Catch ex As Exception
        DataSetMovie = Nothing
        Throw (ex)
    End Try
    Return DataSetMovie
End Function
Public Function addMovie(ByVal film_naam As String, ByVal film_hoofdrol As String) As Boolean
    Dim bStatus As Boolean = False
    Try
        Prepare_StoredProcedureCall("addMovie")

        With CommandMovie.Parameters
            .AddWithValue("film_naam", film_naam)
            .AddWithValue("film_status", 0)
            .AddWithValue("film_hoofdrol", film_hoofdrol)

        End With
        CommandMovie.ExecuteNonQuery()
        sqlTransaction.Commit()
        bStatus = True
    Catch ex As Exception
        sqlTransaction.Rollback()
        objLoggingService.WriteLine(strApplicationName, ex.Message)
        Throw (ex)
    End Try
    Finish_StoredProcedureCall()
    Return bStatus
End Function
```

Hope anyone can help me :)

Comment: What is ***Logging.Logging*** ?

Answer (score 1):

In your code when you addMovie the command stored procedure you pass in 3 parameters, but your sproc only takes in 2 parameters.

Answer (score 0):

From what i can figure out, your problem is that you do not call `CreateConnection` and create a new connection.
In your `Prepare_StoredProcedureCall` sub, you do this: ` CommandMovie = New SqlCommand(strStoredProcedure, conMovie)
        CommandMovie.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure

```
    adapMovie = New SqlDataAdapter(CommandMovie)
    DataSetMovie = New DataSet()

    conMovie.Open()
```

`
Problem is that conMovie is not created at this point. You need to do something like this:

```
 CreateConnection
 CommandMovie = New SqlCommand(strStoredProcedure, conMovie)
    CommandMovie.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure

    adapMovie = New SqlDataAdapter(CommandMovie)
    DataSetMovie = New DataSet()

    conMovie.Open()
```

Edit:
I noticed you do not have `End Class` in your .vb file for this particular class. Could this be the problem?
P.S: If you already figured this out, sorry i was too late to help you:)

Comment: No no,I have made my connection properly. Because i can add already clients to another table. So that's not the problem